# How to rename a file in Terminal?

Tags: files

I have:

1. `/home/user/my_static`
2. `/home/user/static/`

How do I rename `my_static` to `static` and remove `static`(2)?

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Use:

```
mv "old location" "new location"

mv /home/user/my_static /home/user/static
```

That command is used for moving and renaming files and directories.

Comment: For experienced users this comment is superfluous, but it's worth noting this will also unlink (remove) the original `static` directory.

Comment: Sometime you may want to back the file up, like a config file, use `cp /home/file1 /home/file1.bak` you will have 2 files.

Answer (score 25):

A simple way to rename files and folders is with the `mv` command (shortened from “move”). Its primary purpose is moving files and folders, but it can also **rename** them since the act of renaming a file is interpreted by the filesystem as moving it from one name to another.

The syntax is:

```
mv (option) file1.ext file2.ext
```

where “file1.ext” is the “old” name of the file, and “file2.ext” the new name.

And to remove, you can use the command:

```
rm -f filename
```

Hope that helped.